# How to grab Users personal list in Firebase to a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to simply fetch a users favourite maps onto a tableview.
something that i thought would be very basic but turned out to be extremely difficult.

The code here is the best that i have managed so far, Attempting to somehow reference a (users id) with a (yourmaps id) to fetch specific information.

For example. Since the user has made 1 map his favourite(with id (-LpY4XEER-b21hwMi9sp)). I want to look through all maps within root["yourmap"] and only fetch his map onto a tableview.

**Firebase**

```
"users" {
  "6g55cHXH4begwooHQvO4EKNV3xm1" : {
    "photoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleap...",
    "username" : "lbarri",
    "yourmaps" : {
      "-LpY4XEER-b21hwMi9sp" : true
    }
  }
}


"yourmaps": {
  "-LpY4XEER-b21hwMi9sp" : {
    "author" : {
      "photoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v...",
      "uid" : "6g55cHXH4begwooHQvO4EKNV3xm1",
      "username" : "lbarri"
    },
    "mapmoderators" : {
      "6g55cHXH4begwooHQvO4EKNV3xm1" : true
    },
    "mapphotoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis...",
    "mapusername" : "Hello World"
  },
  "-LpYo_pQ8zIOGHHlNU1Q" : {
    "author" : {
      "photoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v...3",
      "uid" : "RLFK9xnvhccTu2hbNHq0v05J2A13",
      "username" : "lbarri"
    },
    "mapmoderators" : {
      "RLFK9xnvhccTu2hbNHq0v05J2A13" : true
    },
    "mapphotoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...",
    "mapusername" : "Dream"
  }
}
```

**Swift**

```
    func getCurrentUserMaps() {
        guard let userProfile = UserService.currentUserProfile else { return }
        let currentUserId = userProfile.uid

        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserId)
        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let root = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            if let mapsByUser = root!["yourmaps"] as? [String: Bool] {
                for (documentId, status) in mapsByUser {
                    if status {
                        // Document is true, check for the maps
                        self.fetchyourmaps(key: documentId, owner: currentUserId)
                    }
                }
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    func fetchyourmaps(key:String, owner:String) {
        let yourMapRef = Database.database().reference().child("yourmaps")
        yourMapRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
            let user = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            if let mapsByUser = user!["mapmoderators"] as? [String: Bool] {
                for (userId, status) in mapsByUser {
                    if userId == owner && status == true {
                        print("Owner \(owner) manages this \(user)")

                        var tempYourMap = [YourMapProfile]()
                        for key in (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)! {
                            let childSnapshot = key as? DataSnapshot
                            let dict = childSnapshot!.value as? [String:AnyObject]                           
                            let author = dict!["author"] as? [String:AnyObject]
                            let uid = author!["uid"] as? String      
                            let username = author!["username"] as? String
                            let photoURL = author!["photoURL"] as? String
                            let url = URL(string:photoURL!)
                            let mapusername = dict!["mapusername"] as? String

                            let mapphotoURL = dict!["mapphotoURL"] as? String
                            let mapurl = URL(string:mapphotoURL!)

                            let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: uid!, username: username!, photoURL: url!, mapPoints: mapPoints!)
                            let yourmapprofile = YourMapProfile(mapid: childSnapshot!.key as! String, mapauthor: userProfile, mapusername: mapusername!, mapphotoURL: mapurl!)

                            tempYourMap.append(yourmapprofile)

                        }
                        self.yourmaps = tempYourMap
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

`print("Owner \(owner) manages this \(user)")`  does print the correct maps onto the console

After that line it is when i cant figure out how to package the information to my tableview.

I have searched everywhere for information on how to retrieve data from Firebase when referencing one root folder to another but i cant find anything helpful. So any link/guide/ tutorial etc would be appreciated and i'll gladly take it from there. Is this at least how you are supposed to do it?

Comment: So, you are grabbing the map id from the user ("-LpY4XEER-b21hwMi9sp") and then trying to reference "yourmaps" and trying to pull the map with that identifier and create some sort of object with the returned dictionary? If that is the case, at what point exactly is this not performing as expected?

Comment: What you should be able to do is something like, after observing the user and grabbing the `mapId`: `Database.database().reference().child("yourmaps").child(mapId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in }`

Comment: I did try that but i can't seem to figure out how to translate that into my Tableview then. The code then works fine until the  line --> for key in (snapshot.value as NSDictionary)! {

Comment: Im assuming `yourMaps` is the dataSource for your table view?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Are you having issues with the line `if let mapsByUser = user!["mapmoderators"]`? Shouldn't it be something like `if let mapsByUser = user!["-LpY4XEER-b21hwMi9sp"]["mapmoderators"]`

Comment: Because all of the keys in "yourmaps" are mapIds, not "author", "mapmoderators", "mapphotoURL", and "mapusername"?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried to simplify the information for this question but i forgot to remove those fields. The problem seems to be on how the content is packaged and not the content within. I think the 3 lines under (var tempYourMap = [YourMapProfile]() are the incorrect ones.

Comment: for example. When i fetch the data through --- > let yourMapRef = Database.database().reference().child("yourmaps") i can easily grab all content perfectly with --- >for child in snapshot.children { -----> let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot. That however grabs the data directly and not through the user.

Comment: Is tempYourMap empty after the for loop?

Comment: Yea it loops and fetches the map info as a collection.

Comment: Can you put a break point in `if let mapsByUser = user!["mapmoderators"] as? [String: Bool] { *breakpoint here* }` just to make sure this conditional is actually getting called? Again, I don't think that `user!["mapmoderators"]` would return anything.

Comment: I think you should first do something like `if let mapsByUser = user!["-LpY4XEER-b21hwMi9sp"]`

Comment: It code seems to work well until that point. it also prints --> print("Owner \(owner) manages this \(user)") correctly. The users id is "6g55cHXH4begwooHQvO4EKNV3xm1" and im trying to print his map id which is "-LpY4XEER-b21hwMi9sp".

Comment: Shouldn’t you be using the word “map” instead of “user”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this but here's two: Option 1 is to leverage a deep query to get the maps that are this users favorites. The second is to iterate over the users maps and pull each one at a time.

Option 1:

Start with a maps node like this

```
allMaps
   map_0
      favorite_of
         uid_0: true
         uid_3: true
      map_user_name: "Larry"
   map_1
      favorite_of
         uid_2: true
      map_user_name: "Moe"
   map_2
      favorite_of
         uid_0: true
      map_user_name: "Curly"
```

Then, a deep query to get all the favorite maps of uid_0

```
func queryToGetMyFavoriteMaps() {
    let uid = "uid_0"
    let ref = self.ref.child("allMaps")
    let path = "favorite_of/" + uid
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: path).queryEqual(toValue: true)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            print(child) //prints the map_0 & map_2 nodes since that's the favorite onces
        }
    })
}
```

Option 2

Change up the allMaps node since we won't be doing a query

```
allMaps
   map_0
      map_user_name: "Larry"
   map_1
      map_user_name: "Moe"
   map_2
      map_user_name: "Curly"
```

and then the users node will be something like this

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Frank"
      favorite_maps:
         map_0: true
         map_2: true
   uid_1
      name: "Leroy"
      favorite_maps:
         map_1: true
```

and then the code that reads uid_0's favorite_maps node, and gets the keys from that snapshot, and then iterates over them, reading the map nodes one at a time.

```
func iterateToGetFavoriteMaps() {
    let uid = "uid_0"
    let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(uid)
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let mapRefs = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "favorite_maps").value as? [String: Any] {
            let mapKeys = mapRefs.keys //note mapKeys is a Dict so we can directly access the keys
            for key in mapKeys {
                let mapRef = self.ref.child("allMaps").child(key)
                mapRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { mapSnapshot in
                    let name = mapSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "mapUserName").value as? String ?? "No Name"
                    print(name)
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```